# Migrating off of the MSDKUI

Tags: here-api, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

I have an old project that needs updating. It is using the MSDKUI.
There is a note at the bottom of the MSDKUI iOS githib page:
https://github.com/heremaps/msdkui-ios

> Maintenance Notice
> The MSDKUI project will be discontinued as it is incompatible with the new 4.x HERE SDK releases.

I am using the Enterprise API for the truck routing features. The Enterprise API is on v3 and the Navigation API is on v4

1. Do I migrate off of the Enterprise API to the Navigation API?
2. If I can continue using the Enterpise API do I need to immediately come off of the MSDKUI? Or can I continue to use that + the Enterprise API for a while until the Enterprise API moves to v4?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the maintenance notice: The HERE team does not plan any additional feature implementation for the future. This repository will stay online and it can still be forked and used for commercial or non-commercial projects, but we plan only limited maintenance work from now on.

There is no need to switch immediately but I would recommend to get in [contact](https://developer.here.com/contact-us) with us to start evaluating the Navigation release based on 4.x.

Comment: To clarify, should I move away from the Premium API to the Navigation API? I have not read that the Premium iOS API is being deprecated also: These are the Premium and Navigation API's I am referring to: https://developer.here.com/products/here-sdk

Comment: There is no immediate need of moving away from Premium SDK(3.x). There will be a proper communication and action plan for the migration.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to migrate from the older 3.x version to the new 4.x editions, e.g. the HERE SDK [Navigate Edition](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk-navigate/4.8.0.0/dev_guide/index.html) for iOS.

It has excellent [truck features](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk-navigate/4.8.0.0/dev_guide/topics/navigation.html#truck-guidance), like dedicated truck warning functions and truck map layers.

The documentation for 4.x also provides a [migration guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk-navigate/4.8.0.0/dev_guide/topics/migration.html) that explains how easily you can migrate from Premium to Navigate.

Regrading the MSDKUI toolkit: There's no equivalent yet, but if you consider to switch to Flutter, then you can benefit from this new [Ref App](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-ref-app-flutter) project on GitHub. It has a lot of ready-made UI and it's free to use in commercial apps.